# How can I visualize image using qiskit in vscode?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pip, quantum-computing, qiskit

I'm now trying to run qiskit visualization functions(e.g. .draw() methods) in vscode.

I use latest version of Python, 3.11.1, and followed Getting Started Qiskit in [here](https://qiskit.org/documentation/getting_started.html).
Also I installed [qiskit extension](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=qiskit.qiskit-vscode) in vscode.

However, when I run a qiskit code, the visualization functions don't work, even though code is compiled successfully.

I checked visualizing modules(mathplotlib, etc.) were installed.

I tried to re-install Python and vscode, including downgrading Python to 3.8. And it didn't work.

Additionally, qiskit-chemistry and qiskit-aqua installation warnings are pop-upped, but installation doesn't work.

I really don't know it is related on this problem, but I think maybe it's not since qiskit-aqua is deprecated.

The following screenshot is result of the qiskit test code.

[result of running](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AUdF0.png)

draw() and plot_histogram() doesn't work as you can see.

How can I fix this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These functions are meant to be used in Python Notebooks - they won't show up in normal `.py` files. Try using VSCode's Jupyter Notebook (`.ipynb` files) feature instead.